# Different events models on same calendar with simple_calendar, Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

I have two different models: `Note` and `Todo`. Each with its own different attributes I want to display on the calendar.

I'm trying to display more than one kind of `events` on my `simple_calendar`, but keep getting an error, `undefined method 'start_time' for #<Note::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007ffce4182638>`

Here's my code:

```
<%= calendar number_of_days: 1, events: [@notes, @todos] do |date, notes, todos| %>
  <%= date %>
  <% notes.each do |note| %>
    <div>
      <%= note.title %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  <% todos.each do |todo| %>
    <div>
      <%= todo.title %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I am assuming by `simple_calendar` you mean you are using [simple_calendar](https://github.com/excid3/simple_calendar) gem. If yes, then it seems like your Note model is not following the contract specified by the gem. For e.g. please refer [this](https://github.com/excid3/simple_calendar#rendering-events) section wherein a para starts with _If you already have a model with a start time attribute called something other than start_time or accesses it through a relationship.._ . See if that's helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is because `events: [@notes, @todos]` is creating a new Array with two elements `@notes` and `@todos` and when it calls `start_time` it's doing against `@Notes` which is an ActiveRecord Relation (on Rails latest version) instead of a `Note` object.

I ran into this post looking for a way to insert multiple event types in a Day using [excid3's simple_calendar](http://excid3.github.io/simple_calendar). At the moment I didn't come up with how to solve it, I think you were looking for the same.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into same issue.

The `events` takes a relation and the syntax you have used is correct in case of forms and a few other utilities but it probably has not caught the eye of developer of this gem.

**Solution (work-around)**

```
<%= calendar number_of_days: 1, events: @notes+@todos do |date, events| %>
  <%= date %>
  <% events.each do |event| %>
    <div>
      <%= event.title %>    <%# if both models have same column that you wanna show like this case, otherwise see solution below.%>
    </div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

**OR**

```
<%= calendar number_of_days: 1, events: @notes+@todos do |date, events| %>
  <%= date %>
  <% events.each do |event| %>
    <div>
      <% if event.is_a? Note %>
        <% "show_something_for_note" %>
      <% elsif event.is_a? Todo %>
        <% "show_something_for_todo" %>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

How's that? ;)